# Data extracted by NetCDF is mirrored in the X axis

Tags: python, arrays, netcdf

Hi I have the elevation map from the side: https://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/mgg/global/relief/ETOPO1/data/bedrock/grid_registered/netcdf/

I want to extract the elevation data of the dataset and change the interpolated values with it. Unfortunately I have the problem that the NetCDF data is mirrored in the X axis! How can I solve this problem?

```
dfl= pd.DataFrame({
    'Latitude' : lat.reshape(-1),
    'Longitude': lon.reshape(-1),
    'Altitude': height.reshape(-1)[0::-1],
    'Value': value.reshape(-1),
});
print(dfl)
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. NOAA's Etop dataset is well established, and it is extremely unlikely something is wrong with the coordinates. Please check your code

Comment: Is it just that lon is in [0, 360] and you’re expecting [-180, 180]? Can you please show us your code, the result of `print(ds)`, etc, ideally as a [mre], so we can help diagnose?

Comment: I found my error: sorry after I asked the question I imedatly found it (I look for this over 1 day) should I delete my question?